# Copying sheet to another Excel workbook using C# and OpenXML

Tags: c#, openxml

Sheet 2 contains the lists which are created previously, and sheet 1 contains the links to sheet 2, so when I generate sheet 1, I want sheet 2 to be copied to the workbook.

```
static void CopySheet(string filename, string sheetName, string clonedSheetName) {
    //Add new sheet to main workbook part
    Sheets sheets = workbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>();
    Sheet copiedSheet = new Sheet();
    copiedSheet.Name = clonedSheetName;
    copiedSheet.Id = workbookPart.GetIdOfPart(clonedSheet);
    copiedSheet.SheetId = (uint)sheets.ChildElements.Count + 1;
    sheets.Append(copiedSheet);
    //Save Changes
    workbookPart.Workbook.Save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
using (ExcelPackage ExcelFile = new ExcelPackage(new System.IO.FileInfo(@"C:\temp\MyExcelFile.xlsx")))
{
    ExcelFile.Workbook.Worksheets.Copy("SheetToCopyName", "SheetToCopyToName");
}
```

This is done with EPPlus which uses OpenXML library. If you're using another library let me know.

Comment: actually i'm working with something like this. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d0971ec0-7d22-4c38-b686-b32e6bd01d44/how-to-copy-spreadsheet-to-another-excel-file-in-openxml?forum=oxmlsdk. but i want it just to copy sheet2 to another workbook containing sheet1